# Facebook login button hangs then crashes ios simulator on 5.1 but not 6

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-login, ios5.1

I'm pretty sure I have all the right sdks included the right ones are  set to optional but on ios 5.1 when I click the facebook login button it hangs then crashes a while later. The error trace gives me a whole bunch of errors within the Facebook classes that are a bit incomprehensible. The last call in the trace is

`[FBSession isSystemAccountStoreAvailable]`;

Anything else I should check? Works fine in 6.1. The facebook sample app works fine on the 5.1 simulator and I've copied every setting I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this crash is due to an infinite loop. This may be due to the Server error that Facebook fixed yesterday related to the 3.5 SDK. It should be working for you know.

Facebook has fixed a server error that was causing this for a lot of developers. However, the server fix only makes the infinite loop problem less likely to happen. It is still there. I created a new bug to track the infinite loop problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/446010282155033

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in SDK 3.5.1. Please update the SDK and you should be good to go.